# Installing a gcc and make on a clean SUSE 10 machine

Tags: installation, rpm, sles

I received a clean SUSE 10 machine which I need to install a development environment on.

Currently, I need to install GCC 3.2.3 and GNU Make. However I am having trouble bootstrapping GCC. I searched for RPMs, but didn't find any, and I'm not sure I even know how to install them.

What is the fastest way to install these two components?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/54670/where-are-the-repos-with-development-tools-for-suse-sled-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, GCC & friends are part of SUSE. You should be able to install them from the same media that SUSE was installed with.

If you don't have the SUSE media, use `yum` to install them from some online repository. These should be configured too, but in case they're not, you need to configure a repository in yum.

You can use any repo for SUSE 10, e.g. this:

http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.opensuse.org/discontinued/SL-10.1/inst-source/